# Variance of ratio of a time series of random numbers

Tags: variance, covariance

Say we have a time series($X_0, X_1, ..., X_n$) with only the first element $X_0$ known, rest being random. How can we express:

$$ {\rm var} \frac{X_n}{X_0} = f({\rm var} \frac{X_i}{X_{i-1}})$$

Don't know how to proceed beyond writing the left side as
$$\frac{X_n}{X_0} = \prod\frac{X_i}{X_{i-1}} $$

Intuitively, the left side has to be equal to sum of variance of consecutive terms plus some covariance terms but not sure how to get that.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I do not think there is a general answer to this question, it highly depends on the model.

Comment: @Xi'an I have removed out the suggested solution, it doesn't look correct.

Comment: You should also remove the last sentence and the first comment.